# Виртуальные хосты в nginx извне в docker

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, virtual-hosts

Пробую запустить проект в docker на nginx + php-fpm. Ubuntu 20.10.

Есть docker-compose из стандартных примеров:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./sites:/var/www
      - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    links:
      - php
  php:
    build: ./images/php
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      - ./sites:/var/www
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /etc/mysql:/etc/mysql
      - ./logs/mysql:/var/log/mysql
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql-files:/var/lib/mysql-files
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: sait
```

И конфиг nginx:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name _________;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/_________;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Локально всё поднимается, через hosts можно указать виртуальные хосты и обращаться к ним. А как заставить такую конфигурацию обращаться к виртуальным хостам извне? A-записи прописаны, по внешнему IP-адресу попадаю корректно на дефолтный проект, а по доменному имени - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
В ufw порты открыты, ну и по внешнему ip и пускает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете установить nginx в качестве прокси сервера. Проксировать nginx который в докере на ваш внешний.
Нужно что б контейнер nginx имел какой-нибудь, внешний порт, к примеру 33333:80.

Это конфиг для проксирования уже на основном nginx сервере.

```
location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.3.33:33333;
    }
```

Comment: А докер разве не слушал 80-й порт и так? Для чего прокси между докером и внешним миром, если докер слушал 80 и 443 порты?
А ip здесь (proxy_pass http://192.168.3.33:33333;) - это какой ip?
Я попробовал вариант с прокси, но с proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:33333, который слушает докер. Всё осталось также. Локально всё ок. Извне только по ip могу открыть default-ный проект, виртуальные - не работают